# Arduino send bad signal to interrupt pin

Tags: arduino

I have connected coin hopper and coin acceptor to one arduino uno, coin acceptor connected to pin 2, coin hopper to pin 3 - sensor and pin 7 - relay. When coin hopper switch relay, it is executing coininterrupt

for coin hopper I am using this script [link](https://gist.github.com/shahrulnizam/8b315bacab8dbd7dd5df14a630463431)
coin acceptor script: [link](https://miliohm.com/coin-acceptor-or-coin-sensor-tutorial-with-arduino)

I need this 2 scripts working on 1 arduino

my code:

```
#define SENSOR  3
#define RELAY   7
#define ACCEPTOR 2

volatile boolean insert = false;

int pulse=0,count;               
char sen;
int temp=0;
unsigned long int timer;             

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(SENSOR,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(RELAY,OUTPUT);
  sen=digitalRead(SENSOR);
  digitalWrite(RELAY, HIGH);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(ACCEPTOR), coinInterrupt, RISING);
}

void loop()
{
  if (insert) {
    insert = false;
    Serial.println("coin");
    delay(1000);
  }

  if(Serial.available())
  {
    timer=millis();
    // temp is amount to dispense send to arduino
    temp=Serial.parseInt();
    if(temp>0){
      digitalWrite(RELAY,LOW);}
  }

  sen=(sen<<1)|digitalRead(SENSOR);
  
  // if hopper sensor read drop coin
  if(sen==1)
  {
    timer=millis();
    pulse++;
    sen&=0x03;
    Serial.println("out 1");
    
    //if dispensed coins equal with coins to dispense stop engine
    if(pulse==temp)
    {
      digitalWrite(RELAY,HIGH);
      pulse=0;
      temp=0;
    }
  }

  // if amount dispensed is not equal with amount to dispense and engine running, stop
  if((digitalRead(RELAY)==LOW)&(millis()-timer>2000))
  {
    digitalWrite(RELAY,HIGH);
    pulse=0;
    temp=0;
  }
}

void coinInterrupt() {
  insert = true;
}
```

I was trying to change pins (arduino uno support interrupts on pin 2 and 3 only) but problem still appears so I guess there is issue in the code

Answer (score 0):

your sketch does not run in this state :
first fix errors :

declare insert as volatile

remove cpulse (not used anywhere)

change 'if()' to (I suppose) 'if (insert) ....'

remove stuff with 'sen' var : simply use if(digitalRead(SENSOR)) or if(!digitalRead(SENSOR))
except if you need to store relay state.

use logical operators like || or && unless you really need bitwise operations

example of result sketch :

```
#define SENSOR  3
#define RELAY   7

volatile boolean insert = false;
byte amountToDispense = 0;

int pulse = 0;
int temp = 0;
unsigned long int timer;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(SENSOR, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(RELAY, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RELAY, HIGH);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), coinInterrupt, RISING);
}

void loop()
{
  if (insert ) {
    insert = false;
    Serial.println("coin");
    delay(1000);
  }

  if (Serial.available())
  {
    timer = millis();
    temp = Serial.parseInt();
    if (temp > 0) {
      //amountToDispense = Serial.read() - 48;
      digitalWrite(RELAY, LOW);
    }
  }

  if (digitalRead(SENSOR))
  {
    timer = millis();
    pulse++;
    Serial.println("out 1");
    if (pulse >= temp)
    {
      digitalWrite(RELAY, HIGH);
      pulse = 0;
      temp = 0;
    }
  }

  if (!digitalRead(RELAY) && (millis() - timer > 2000))
  {
    digitalWrite(RELAY, HIGH);
    pulse = 0;
    temp = 0;
  }
}

void coinInterrupt() {
  insert = true;
}
```

Comment: I have fixed code in first post, your solution didn't work, coin hopper didn't stop working after sending amount to dispense (sensor not counting pulses) I still have issue, after dispensing, hopper send signal to interrupt, could it be because of bad electric connection?

Comment: add  pinMode(ACCEPTOR, INPUT); in setup before attachInterrupt.

Comment: Arduino pins default to INPUT. unlikely going to solve the problem.

Comment: First put a 'return();' at end of 'if (insert ) {....}' to eliminate other code interaction and validate interrupt. Split code into separate functions for a better knowledge and debugging.

Answer (score 0):

What is this supposed to do?

```
sen=(sen<<1)|digitalRead(SENSOR);
```

You init sen with digitalRead(SENSOR);

Assuming that pin is LOW when you start the sketch and turns HIGH, sen will become 1.

Next you do sen &= 0x03 so sen is still 1.

Again `sen=(sen<<1)|digitalRead(SENSOR);` , sen will either be 2 or 3.

Next loop run `sen=(sen<<1)|digitalRead(SENSOR);` sen is now 4 or 6. and so on...

I don't have time to think about what you want to achieve but this is definitely a problem as you'll only enter `if (sen == 1)`  once and never again.

If this is not sufficient you should probably improve your post as it is unclear what arduino sends bad signal to interrup pin is supposed to mean. That doesn't make sense. Explain the expected behaviour of your program and how it behaves instead. add more comments so it becomes clear what you intend to do with each block of code so we don't have to interpret

Comment: I have get 2 separated scripts to manage coin acceptor and coin hopper. I need to connect it together. When scripts are running separately, everything is fine but when I connect them together, hopper send signal to acceptor when relay change state.
Coin hopper oryginal script: [link](https://gist.github.com/shahrulnizam/8b315bacab8dbd7dd5df14a630463431)
Coin acceptor:
[link](https://miliohm.com/coin-acceptor-or-coin-sensor-tutorial-with-arduino)